# How to fix 'ffmpeg.load() failed to fetch' TypeError?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, ffmpeg

I'm trying to create a function that adds a text watermark to a video in Next.js using ffmpeg and I'm keep running into the same error and I've no idea how to fix it.

> TypeError: Failed to fetch
> await ffmpeg.load();

No errror in code, error only occurs in browser after I click Add Watermark button.

Server component: `app/api/addwatermark.ts`

```
import { createFFmpeg, fetchFile } from '@ffmpeg/ffmpeg';

const ffmpeg = createFFmpeg({ log: true });

export default async function addWatermark(
  inputFile: File,
  text: string
): Promise<string> {
  if (!ffmpeg.isLoaded()) {
    await ffmpeg.load();
    // Error ☝️
  }

  ffmpeg.FS('writeFile', inputFile.name, await fetchFile(inputFile));

  await ffmpeg.run(
    '-i',
    inputFile.name,
    '-filter_complex',
    `drawtext=text='${text}':fontfile=Arial.ttf:fontcolor=white@0.8:fontsize=40:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2`,
    'output.mp4'
  );

  const data = ffmpeg.FS('readFile', 'output.mp4');

  const videoUrl = URL.createObjectURL(
    new Blob([data.buffer], { type: 'video/mp4' })
  );

  return videoUrl;
}
```

Client componenet:

```
export default function VideoWatermark() {
  const [inputFile, setInputFile] = useState<File>();
  const [outputFile, setOutputFile] = useState<string>();
  const [text, setText] = useState<string>('');

  const handleFileChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    if (event.target.files && event.target.files.length > 0) {
      setInputFile(event.target.files[0]);
      setOutputFile(undefined);
    }
  };

  const handleWatermark = async () => {
    if (!inputFile) {
      return;
    }
    const output = await addWatermark(inputFile, text);
    setOutputFile(output);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input type='file' onChange={handleFileChange} />
      <br />
      <input
        value={text}
        type='text'
        onChange={(event) => setText(event.target.value)}
      />
      <br />
      <button onClick={handleWatermark}>Add Watermark</button>
      {outputFile && (
        <div>
          <video controls>
            <source src={outputFile} type='video/mp4' />
          </video>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/ffmpegwasm/ffmpeg.wasm

Why it doesn't work in my local environment?

When calling ffmpeg.load(), by default it looks for http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@ffmpeg/core/dist/ to download essential files (ffmpeg-core.js, ffmpeg-core.wasm, ffmpeg-core.worker.js). It is necessary to make sure you have those files served there.

If you have those files serving in other location, you can rewrite the default behavior when calling createFFmpeg():

```
const { createFFmpeg } = FFmpeg;
const ffmpeg = createFFmpeg({
  corePath: "http://localhost:3000/public/ffmpeg-core.js",
  // Use public address if you don't want to host your own.
  // corePath: 'https://unpkg.com/@ffmpeg/core@0.10.0/dist/ffmpeg-core.js'
  log: true,
});
```

I moved the `ffmpeg-core.js`, `ffmpeg-core.wasm` and `ffmpeg-core.worker.js` files to the public folder.

And I used it like below.

```
const ffmpeg = createFFmpeg({ log: true, corePath: `http://localhost:3000/ffmpeg/ffmpeg-core.js` });
```

If you are using `NextJS`, copy the core files to the `/public` in your NextJS project.

For example, copy core files to `/public/ffmpeg`, and test with the following URL in a browser.

http://localhost:3000/ffmpeg/ffmpeg-core.js

Access this URL and verify that the contents of the file are displayed.

Finally, set `corePath` to the URL above and try again.

Comment: I did include: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ffmpeg/core@0.11.0/dist/ffmpeg-core.js - just like you suggest and still not working.